# FirebasePushNotificationPlugin Xamarin for Silent Notifications

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm adding FirebasePushNotificationPlugin to an existing Xamarin Forms project to enable the app to receive data silently in the background. This data is related to external device telemetry so needs to be on all the time in order for the App to work.

The problem I have is that as soon as the user opens the App it asks them to allow notifications which means there is a risk they will not allow them and then nothing works.

Is there a way to setup FirebasePushNotificationPlugin so that when using silent notifications like this it is not required to obtain user permission?

The other issue I notice is when in debug mode and refreshing token every start - I only get a token every other start - I have checked and it is not random its every other start. Is there another setting I am missing?

I am setting up exactly as per the guide and other than these issues it works as expected.

In my main activity:

```
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.ProcessIntent(this, Intent);
```

Then in Application On Create

```
            //Set the default notification channel for your app when running Android Oreo
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            //Change for your default notification channel id here
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.DefaultNotificationChannelId = "DefaultChannel";

            //Change for your default notification channel name here
            FirebasePushNotificationManager.DefaultNotificationChannelName = "General";
        }


        //If debug you should reset the token each time.
            

            #if DEBUG
        FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(this, true);

            #else
          FirebasePushNotificationManager.Initialize(this,false);

            #endif
```

Comment: There is no direct way to setup FirebasePushNotificationPlugin so that when using silent notifications like this it is not required to obtain user permission.